# <ngx-qrcode> isn't known element in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, qr-code, ionic4

Since working for a QR code scanning application in ionic 4, I continuously get the error called as below:

Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'qrc-value' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-qrcode'.
1. If 'ngx-qrcode' is an Angular component and it has 'qrc-value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-qrcode' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

```
<ion-card *ngIf="createdCode">
<ngx-qrcode [ERROR ->][qrc-value]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
<ion-card-content>
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Your question doesn't say if you have declared it in your module, like the error asks you about?

Comment: did you solve it? i have the same problem

Answer (score 7):

Besides import the module in **app.module.ts** (following the instructions on https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-qrcode2) make sure to do the same in the **page-name.module.ts** too.

I've had the same trouble and this solution solved it. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using lazy-loading, import NgxQRCodeModule on the module where is your page, not on app.module.

also try this --

```
use [(qrc-value)] instead of [qrc-value]
<ngx-qrcode [(qrc-value)]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
```

Comment: I've done everything you mentioned above, but still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed `importing the module in app.module.ts`.
Did some check on the packages. Please make sure you are following all the instructions correctly.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-qrcode2

Comment: Still getting the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the npm package that you're using?